# Unable to share controls between size classes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a storyboard containing a UIView built for Compact-Regular size class (iPhone portrait). Now I need to use some of those same controls in landscape iPad Regular-Any. I am using XCode 7.2 which I have found to be extremely buggy.

When in the iPad size class, I can see the controls from the other size class, though they are grayed out. I have tried dragging the greyed out control into the iPad size class, which seems to work, but it remains grayed out and doesn't allow addition of constraints.

I went back to Any-Any and tried to add the controls there, hoping to make them visible in both. With that approach, any outlet or action that I connect only exists in the Any-Any size class and not in the more specific size classes. Accordingly, the outlets/actions don't perform at runtime.

Furthermore, when trying to set an outlet or action in one size class deletes it in the others.

Are these known XCode bugs? Has anyone seen this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the controls in the inspector. Select the control, open the Attribute Inspector and scroll down until you see something like this:

[image]

Click the plus and add the size class to which you want to add that control. Then click the check box.